# What is the difference between VSTS and Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS for code management , version management , agile management and environment management. For last few weeks i have been hearing about Azure Devops. What is Azure Devops ? . How it is going make a difference ?

Answer (score 3):

Azure DevOps is the new name of VSTS. See the details about the rename here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/what-happened-vsts?view=vsts

Comment: So that means , its just lable change only ? , or new features are added ?